# scrollTop duplicating values each time function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 divs that each time one of them is clicked it scrolls down to a common content div called .nbm_specs. The first time you click it scrolls correctly, however any subsequent clicks make the scrolling go crazy and it keeps scrolling up by a small amount each time.
It is acting like it is stacking the offset top each time you click on it.

I have established the scroll in a function that I then call in each .on CLICK function.

```
//hidel all at start    
$(".prostar,.X10,.x20,.x23,.x30,.x46,.xstar").fadeOut(0); 

//Scrol when clicekd

function SpecScrol(){
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".nbm_specs").offset().top -80}, 1500);
}

//NAVIGATION SECTION FOR MODELS
$("#prostar").on('click', function() {
   $(".prostar").fadeIn(0);
   $(".X10").fadeOut(0); 
   SpecScrol();  
});

$("#X10").on('click', function() {
   $(".X10").fadeIn(0);
   $(".prostar").fadeOut(0);
   SpecScrol();
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

The issue was that there are multiple .nbm_specs div and the code wasn't sure which to go to and getting all confused. Fixed this by creating a blank div just above the .nbm_specs div with a unique id.